# 100% height, no scrollbars

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can I make this layout be always 100%, stick to the bottom and not beyond so no scrollbars are needed?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/HsPtp/1/

Whatever I do I get some extra space on the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that `overflow:hidden` will hide some of your content. The scroll bars are appearing because of your height/padding figures:

1. On `.colmask` you have set `height:100%`. This is relative to the body.
2. On `#header` you have set `padding-bottom:16px`.

This means the full height of your page is 100% + 16px.

**Option 1:**
If you want your page to have no scrollbars and always show the bottom of the content you need to change your height/padding figures so that they add up to 100%.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HsPtp/12/

```
#header {height:5%;} /* Instead of using padding-bottom */
.colmask {height: 90%;}
#footer {height:4.5%;} /* Not 5% To allow for the 1px border you set */
```

**Option 2:**

As long as you know there isn't going to be any other content other than the footer right down at the bottom you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/HsPtp/6/

```
html, body {overflow: hidden;}
#footer {position:fixed; bottom:0;height:20px;} /* height added so effect can be seen */
```

This essentially will cut off the extra 16px from the `#header` at the bottom, and then remove `#footer` from the flow of page and fix it at the bottom. So technically there will be 36px (16px `#header` padding + 20px `#footer` height) at the bottom of your page that will be cut off and covered by the footer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you confirmed my suspicions that it was a problem with paddings, but unfortunately none of the solutions you gave solve the problem I'm having. I want images in the center column to not be chopped off at the bottom but to resize with max-height:100% so it's always visible. Like i'm trying to do here http://jsfiddle.net/HsPtp/7/  the image is not scaling vertically

Comment: @tomalak: I would say it is because it does actually answer his original question. The comment brings in a whole new question.

Comment: "none of the solutions you gave solve the problem I'm having" Accepting answers is for when your problem is solved. Now please don't misunderstand me: this is still a great, technically accurate answer!

Comment: @tomalak: Yes, but his original problem i.e. the main question was solved. He goes on to ask in the comment "*I want images in the center column to not be chopped off at the bottom but to resize with max-height:100% so it's always visible.*" which was not mentioned in the question at all. Scaling images is a totally different issue. Which is why he then asked the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885724/get-images-to-resize-vertically

Comment: @tw16: OK, question fail then :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to html,body in CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/HsPtp/2/

Comment: I want everything to be visible first

Comment: The space at the bottom that needs scrollbars to be seen

Comment: Won't happen if you leave `height: 100%` on `.colmask` and relative to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents: I would putt header and colmask into a container div and use something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        overflow:hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```